# Nokogiri and creating a hash from two items - Error retrieves all as string

Tags: ruby, hash, nokogiri

I am trying to retrieve two elements both with nine responses from an xml file with Nokogiri. Retrieval itself isn't hard:

```
number = @doc.xpath('//Race/@RaceNumber').text
# => "123456789"
```

But it selects it as one string. And this is the other reduced for brevity:

```
name = @doc.css('NameRaceFull')
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1775154 name="NameRaceFull" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1774448 name="StakesGroupId" value="346">]
```

My goal is to create a hash and so on for each number and name

```
{ 1 => "Greenland Australia Maribyrnong Trial Stakes" }
```

But with the retrieval pulling it all as a string, how would I get this to work?

My solution was to create two arrays and then do `Hash[number.zip(name)]`, but if this is possible in one go, that would be great.

```
@doc.xpath('//Race/@RaceNumber').text.each do |name|
  arr << name
end
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "123456789":String
```

The example part of the XML I am getting this from is this.

```
<Race RaceCode="5038498" CurrentRaceStage="Results" RaceNumber="1">
      <NameRaceFull StakesGroupId="346">Greenland Australia Maribyrnong Trial Stakes</NameRaceFull>
```

Comment: `{ number : name, number : name}` is invalid.

Comment: `{ 1: Greenland Australia Maribyrnong Trial Stakes }` is invalid.

Comment: @sawa   its an example of the hash output I desire not actual code.

Comment: It does not represent a Ruby hash in any sense. Now it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve it:

```
hash = Hash[doc.xpath('//Race').map{|race|
  [race["RaceNumber"].to_i, race.xpath('NameRaceFull').text]
}]
```

The output hash:

```
{1=>"Foo", 2=>"Goo", 3=>"Hoo"}
```

The code works like this:

1. Find all the `Race` items and iterate on them.
2. Each iteration produces a key (i.e. race number) and a value (i.e. the full name).
3. Combine the results to produce your hash.

Note that Ruby offers a variety of ways to convert items to hashes, and you can use any way you prefer. For example, `Hash#[]`, `Array#to_h`, `Enumerable#inject`, etc.

Here's a complete code example with simplified XML for clarity:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

xml=<<-qqq
<Races>
<Race RaceNumber="1"><NameRaceFull>Foo</NameRaceFull></Race>
<Race RaceNumber="2"><NameRaceFull>Goo</NameRaceFull></Race>
<Race RaceNumber="3"><NameRaceFull>Hoo</NameRaceFull></Race>
</Races>
qqq

doc=Nokogiri.parse(xml)

hash = Hash[doc.xpath('//Race').map{|race|
  [race["RaceNumber"].to_i, race.xpath('NameRaceFull').text]
}]

p hash
```

Comment: I get a nomethoderror [56] pry(main)> doc=Nokogiri.parse("tiny.xml")
=> #(Document:0x25decf4 { name = "document" })
[57] pry(main)> hash = doc.xpath('//Race').map{|race|
[57] pry(main)*   [race["RaceNumber"].to_i, race.xpath('NameRaceFull').text]
[57] pry(main)* }.to_h  
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for []:Array
from (pry):76:in `__pry__'

Comment: You're using an older Ruby. I'm updating the question now with the syntax for older Ruby.